# Improving performance of a view with many left joins

Tags: sql-server, left-join, database-performance

I'm new to performance enhancement of SQL queries and given a task to enhance it for a view.

This view definition has about 20 left joins applied on it which I believe is hampering the performance - it takes around 9 seconds to retrieve 35K odd rows on a local server.

What is the best way to enhance its performance?

Comment: Is this some sort of "[uber-view](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/03/07/bad-habits-to-kick-creating-the-uber-view.aspx)" which satisfies a lot of different queries, not all of which need columns from all 20 tables?

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider whether you need LEFT joins as opposed to INNER joins. With no knowledge of the data involved we can't give you that.
2. Run an Execution Plan on your query.
3. Identify joins where an index may improve performance.
4. Consider de-normalising your database design.

Comment: Cool:) I would like to have more information on the no#3 - "Identify joins where an index may improve performance". This view is being used by a stored proc for SSRS(Reporting Services). INNER JOIN will not help us in this view - we need to have the LEFT JOINs. De-normalising database design does not seem to be an option for us.

Comment: You need an understand of indexes and how they are used when querying data. There are plenty of resources on the web. You can then use the execution plan of your query to identify the what indexes would be of benefit to your query.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing the query.  One possible way to improve performance would be to create indexes for the columns involved in the joins.

If you view the query execution plan, you should be able to see what part of the query is slowing things down.  You could also run the query through the [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575%28v=sql.105%29) and allow the advisor to suggest on which columns indexes would make the most difference.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using this view? I would suggest that if you are using this in proc or like that and then just use few columns out of all columns of view. It could be pretty possible that some of these joins would be redudant as some of them wont even affect the final results and you do not need to join unnecessary tables. Thus best way is to profile where this view is used and what columns are being used each time the view is called and which tables have the required columns.

I would suggest that if you are using this view from other proc or like that than instead of referencing the view reference each tables and use only those tables which are needed.